# Which version of R is compatible with the newest version of Blavaan (August 3rd, 2019)?

Tags: r, vctrs

I would like to use blavaan (version 0.3-5) for my analysis. Installing the package `blavaan` seems to work (i.e., no error messages), but when I try to load the library 'blavaan', I receive the following error message:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘blavaan’ in
>   loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
>   vI[[j]]):  there is no package called ‘pkgbuild’

This is the error message I receive in the newest version of R (3.6.1). I checked, and it appears af if the package `pkgbuild` may not compatible with this version. Therefore, I tried an older version of R (3.5.3) in which blavaan was created. So then it should work, right?
But then again I receive a similar error message. This time for a package called `vctrs`.

For some background: I have experience with `lavaan` ('regular' SEM), and wanted to give blavaan a try. I know my way around lavaan and basic R, but I am not a programmer/mathematician or something like that. I think the best solution for me is to just use a version of R that others know will work, rather than having to program my way around.

This is the code I used, but I don't think that is the issue:

```
install.packages("blavaan", dep = TRUE)

library(blavaan)
```

After installing 'blavaan', I get the following message:

> package ‘blavaan’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked The
>   downloaded binary packages are in [location]

However, after opening the library 'blavaan', I receive the following error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘blavaan’ in
>   loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
>   vI[[j]]):  there is no package called ‘pkgbuild’ [or 'vctrs' etc.]

I have only just started using blavaan (or: trying to...), so I only have tried the newest version of blavaan (0.3-5) that was updated on August 3rd, 2019.

Has anybody since then used blavaan? And if so, which version of R did you use?

Comment: I can install and use it on R 3.6.1 without any issues. Since the package [passes the CRAN checks](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_blavaan.html) it definitely works with the current R version and there is no reason to use an older R version (but good reasons not to, e.g., if you don't build packages from source).

Comment: Did you, during installing, get any messages regarding failing installations for dependencies?

Comment: Roland, yes i did receive the following message: Warning: dependency ‘genefilter’ is not available. 
It is good to know that it works for you in R 3.6.1, thank you.

Comment: I found that the dependency genefilter is part of Bioconductor, which can be installed using the following code:
install.packages("BiocManager")
library("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("genefilter")
But then, when installing genefilter, it cannot unzip: Error in unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) :
Once I have installed genefilter, is this then automatically available to the blavaan package? Or do I have to take an additional step?

Comment: blaavan works for me and I don't have genefilter installed. A CRAN package should not have a Bioconductor package as dependency (and as far as I can see blaavan doesn't).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you have any recommendations for me?

Comment: Have you done `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE)` after updating R? Maybe try `remove.packages("blavaan"); update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE); install.packages("blaavan")`? And pay close attention to any messages (warnings, errors or otherwise).

Comment: Btw. , the newest version of pkgbuild is not yet available as a binary. You might need to tell R to install the older binary if you use windows and don't have Rtools installed (usually it should ask).

Comment: Updating packages works; removing blavaan does not: Error in find.package(pkgs, lib) : there is no package called ‘blavaan’

Comment: OK, no problem. Just install it.

Comment: I indeed use windows and do not have Rtools installed. Then how can i install the older binary of pkgbuild?

Comment: What happens if you do `install.packages("pkgbuild")`?

Comment: R tells me there is a binary version available with a later source version, thus the source is installed. Next pkgbuild is successfully unpakced and MD5 sums checked (thus all is normal). However, when preparing for lazy loading: 
Error in findpack(package, lib.loc) : 
  there is no package called 'pkgbuild'
Calls: <Anonymous> -> findpack
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'pkgbuild'
* removing 

And then warning that pkgbuild has non-zero exit status

Comment: Try `options(install.packages.check.source = "no"); install.packages("pkgbuild", type = "binary")`.